# Battery level to output via Bluetooth for external control

Tags: battery, charging, bluetooth

Is there any device to read the phones battery level  ; lets say 10 % to  90% to trigger a signal out over blue tooth;  some apps haves control; like sonoff;  for wifi control but I want to trigger off my phone charger when the battery is at  90% charge.; ; then turn it back on lets say at 50% etc. a blue tooth switch that I can feed into a replay for my power source on a power pak ?
LG phone constantly charge to blow up batteries; or bulge them so the buttons don't work.
Constantly replacing batteries !!
U can add my email for replies; to anyone

Comment: On a rooted device (that is compatible) you could use an app like [Battery Charge Limit](https://github.com/sriharshaarangi/BatteryChargeLimit).

Comment: @Robert IMO, every rooted device that does not have that functionality built-in would benefit from that app (or one like it).  I wish it was possible without root.

Comment: I don't know a device that can read out the battery level, but you can develop your own app to do so. Reading the battery level is simply and there are sample apps available e.g. on Github that show how to send arbitrary data via BLE. As receiver you could use an Arduino with an attached relay. For app development please check https://Stackoverflow.com